Is there a function in R to reduce the number of zeros of a percentage in the y axis of a bar chart?
I wrote the code
ggplot(data = summary_datas) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=member_casual,fill=member_casual)) + 
  labs(title = "Rider Membership data", subtitle= "Difference in the amount of registered riders based on category") + 
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot",plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))

to create a bar chart in R with percentage values in the y-axis but my percentage is in thousands e.g. (10 000%, 20 000%) instead of tens. Please someone should help me out.
I tried using the ylim function but it didn't work

You need to show us an example that we can run.  We don't have summary_datas, so can't try it with what you have included.  That makes it really hard to help you.

I presume you have raw data like 100 and 200 if it is showing up as "10 000%" and "20 000%". Perhaps try scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1, scale = 1/100) if your 100 is supposed to represent 100%.

This is happening because the percent() family of functions are designed to convert proportions (of 1) into percentages.
For example
library(scales)

label_percent()(1)
#> "100%"

label_percent()(.5)
#> "50%"

label_percent()(100)
#> "10 000%"

In order to get sensible labels you'll need to make sure that you're passing proportions to you scale function, rather than pre-formatted percentages.
